# Free ways to collaborate on a project for students without Appflow

Tags: ionic-framework

We are planning to use Ionic for our final year project. Is there a way we can collaborate in one project for free remotely. I know we can use Appflow but we cannot afford the monthly cost for at least 7 months.

Is it possible to run an ionic project from a github repo ? and then different members of the group that has a github account can access that shared repo?

I’m new with Ionic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If cost is an issue, I would highly recommend avoiding AppFlow. Especially since you're talking about a school project where the objective should be to learn something new.

Ionic is a completely 100% open source app development CLI and SDK that you don't need to pay a cent to use. 
(from their front page https://ionicframework.com/framework)

> Ionic Framework is a 100% free and open source project, licensed under MIT. It will always remain free to use, powered by a massive world-wide community.

Ionic is an incredibly useful development tool that I would recommend to anyone looking for a new web technology to learn. You only need to pay if you want the ionic pro and app flow enterprise features. The most arguably useful feature is the automated deployment live remote code reloading options. These are great, but its hard to see the benefit of paying for these things unless you've learned the conventional way of deploying apps to the App Store and the Google Play store first. (Also live reloading is a controversial topic on the Apple App Store and can result in an app rejection more info: https://ionicframework.com/blog/making-sense-of-apples-tos/)

Since you're a student, just know that you can't make a jump from only knowing C++ to making cross platform apps in ionic (well you could try). You'll be much better off having some background in how the web functions (understanding the DOM), first, or else you will have endless misunderstandings, bugs, and general issues with everything and it will be no fun. You may already understand the web, I just think it's worth adding this for anyone reading who may be about to fall in that pothole of jumping in without having enough preliminary knowledge. Also make an effort to understand how ionic is related to angular/react/vue and what they help you achieve collectively. The more you understand what work is being done for you by whom (which framework) the easier it is to debug your errors.

In terms of needing to collaborate with your team mates, that's exactly what git/github are fantastic tools for which will make your code concurrent and allow merging with other contributors branches of work/code.

Again, there is absolutely no reason why you can't use ionic, host the project code on GitHub, and not pay anything for the additional ionic features. Even though those paid ionic features are nice, as a student I would challenge you to avoid it so eventually when you can get an awesome job where the company will pay for ionic pro/app sync and you can appreciate the features they help save time with during development. The question seemed a bit broad, but I hope this helps you make your decision.